# How to configure additional drivers from command line?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ubuntu-drivers, additional-drivers

I want to configure the drivers for my nvidia graphics on my 20.04 system using only the command line (the gui isn't up). I have found the command `ubuntu-drivers` however, it feels incomplete, or incompletely documented.

If I list my drivers with `ubuntu-drivers list` I see things like nvidia-340, nvidia-390, nvidia-driver-418-server (from memory, so perhaps inaccurately named). However, there is no indication of *which* is actually in use.

I had (circumstantial) reason to believe that the nvidia-340 driver was perhaps in use, and the cause of the failure, so I attempted to remove it using `apt purge nvidia-340`. This *claims* to have removed the package, and if I repeat the command, it asserts that there is nothing to remove. However, if I use `apt list nvidia*`, I see a directory called nvidia-340 (and some variants, such as `nvidia-340-dev`, again all names from memory, since I clearly can't use that machine to post this question!)

Also, after the attempt at removal, `ubuntu-drivers list` still shows the exact same list.

So, that's problem number one: do I *need* to get a driver off the list, or is it merely a list of possible options?

The next problem is how to know which driver is selected and in use?

The third problem--really the most important--is how to change which driver is in use? I have tried to issue commands on the form `ubunut-drivers install nvidia-???` and the response is that no driver was found for install.

Any ideas much appreciated!

Cheers,
Toby

Comment: You probably just need `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. Don't try to second-guess it with `apt install` some package. Just let it choose and install the right driver for you. Try that, and see what you get?

Comment: Well, thanks for the thought @popey, however autoinstall says it's deprecated and to use install instead. That did nothing (and indeed, I'm not sure why this would change the currently selected driver anyway). Unfortunately, the latest update broke something in whatever driver was in use, and I need to force it to do something else that works instead.